# How can I set up two sub networks that can communicate by LAN but where only one has internet?

Tags: router, subnet, internet, lan, wan

With only two routers, where one has a connection to the internet, is it possible to set up a second sub network that has no access to the internet, but where devices connected to either router can communicate by LAN with devices connected to other router?

I am currently trying to do this with two ISP routers, I realise these may be unconfigurable but I want to know if it possible with any routers that I will purchase if required. The first router is a Virgin Hub 3.0 (connected to the internet) and the second is an old BT Smart Hub 2, with default configurations apart from changing the subnet ranges (and firewall rule for 1)  as below.

I tried two things after connecting the two routers by ethernet cable (DHCP enabled on both): 1) setting the second router to a subnet range (within the first router's subnet range) where the internet is blocked for these IPs by firewall on the first router, 2) setting the routers to different subnet ranges, 192.168.0.1/24 and 192.168.1.1/24.

Both of these seem to work in that a device connected to the second router with an IP of e.g. 192.168.1.178 cannot connect to the internet.

However, in both setups I had situations where connecting a new device to the second router (by either ethernet or WiFi), resulted in it being given an IP in subnet 192.168.0.1/24 and so it could connect to the internet (presumably because it has a route to the first router by ethernet cable?). In addition, for the second case with different subnets, IP 192.168.1.178 cannot communicate by LAN to 192.168.0.1/24 devices, which is not what I need either.

How can I set this up so devices connected to the second router have access to LAN of first and second router, but no internet connection?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the router models, and the router configurations.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

For hosts on one network to talk to another network, you require a gateway/router in between and the hosts to have (default) routes that point directly or indirectly to the remote network.

You can have all hosts use their local router as default gateway, interconnect the routers and set up a static route on each router for the remote network. Alternatively, you can set up a dynamic routing protocol like OSPF to distribute the routes.

Whether each router has Internet connectivity, only one or neither doesn't matter. It's only relevant for deciding where to point their respective default routes - a router without Internet can use another router as default gateway.

> setting the second router to a subnet range (within the first router's subnet range) ...

No, don't do that. Overlapping subnets won't work. Use separate subnets instead. For a link segment between the routers, you should use a /31 point-to-point subnet if possible.

Comment: By interconnect the routers do you mean directly by ethernet cable, or do you mean I need a third router that sits in between the first and second? If I can do this with the two routers I have, then what would I set the IP static route to? I should add that I can't try this as I don't think there is an option to set static routes on these consumer routers, so trying to work it out blindly before buying new equipment. Thanks

Comment: @MattD Any form of connectivty - direct or via intermediate router(s) will do. You can use any subnet (preferrably /31) for the link segment that doesn't collide with either network. Note that home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help].